# Sublime Text 2 and Xdebug

Tags: debugging, xdebug, sublimetext2

I'd like to use Xdebug with Sublime text 2, I've installed the Xdebug package, now what do I do next? I also have Xdebug installed as a PHP module and its working fine, because I can debug through my Komodo IDE.

Comment: What OS are you in? Have you tried using Goto anything in your menu Shift+Command+p in Mac OS X.

Comment: This one worked:https://github.com/martomo/SublimeTextXdebug

All I had to do after install is to append ?XDEBUG_SESSION_START=sublime.xdebug to my urls

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to download xdebug plugin for sublime text which can be done easily with the help of package manager for sublime text.

after that 
- `Shift+f8`: Open XDebug quick panel
- `f8`: Open XDebug control quick panel when debugger is connected
- `Ctrl+f8`: Toggle breakpoint
- `Ctrl+Shift+f5`: Run to next breakpoint
- `Ctrl+Shift+f6`: Step over
- `Ctrl+Shift+f7`: Step into
- `Ctrl+Shift+f8`: Step out

Answer (score 1):

you can try this plugin

https://github.com/Kindari/SublimeXdebug

have not had time to test it myself though

if you do, it would be nice to report your experience